# Fileupload does not work in Primefaces

Tags: spring, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I have some issues with the `<p:fileUpload>` in Primefaces. At first I tried the snippets in the [Documentation of Fileupload](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf) starting on page 2018.
The first issue was that if I use the snippet, the upload function is not called:

```
public void upload() {
    System.out.println("This is never shown");

    if(file != null) {
            System.out.println("This is never shown");
    }
}
```

html:

```
<h:form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" />
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{fileUploadView.upload}" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>
```

I have tried many other snippets and solutions. Advanced mode, with fileUploadListener, deleted the enctype in h:form, ....

If I choose `mode="simple"` and combine it with `ajax="true"` the function `FileUploadView.upload()` is called, but the file is always NULL.

If I delete  the enctype from the `<h:form>`, the function `FileUploadView.upload()` is called, but the file is always NULL.

I mention the issues above, because this should not work either, because I read all possible solutions on this forum. I also added all suggested `dependencies` and `context-params` and `filter`, but it does not work.

Here I will post my pom.xml, web.xml and the full .java code:
pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.qe</groupId>
    <artifactId>ASN_Application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <name>ASN_Application</name>
    <description>
    </description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>at.qe.sepm.asn_app.Main</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-PFD2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- special test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
            <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Enable jacoco analysis -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>
                        ${coverageAgent}
                    </argLine>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyName>coverageAgent</propertyName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/access_denied.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
  </context-param>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>otf</extension>  
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>ttf</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>woff</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>svg</extension>  
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

FileUploadView.java

```
@Component
@Scope("view")    
public class FileUploadView{
        @Autowired
        private PictureService pictureService;
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        @Autowired
        private AuditLogRepository auditLogRepository;
        private Picture picture;
        private UploadedFile file;

        public Picture getPicture(){
            return picture;
        }

        public void setPicture(Picture picture){
            this.picture = picture;
        }


        public UploadedFile getFile() {
            return file;
        }

        public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            file= new DefaultUploadedFile();
        }

        public void upload() {

            if(file != null) {
                try{
                    System.out.println("This is never shown");

                    AuditLog log = new AuditLog(getAuthenticatedUser().getUsername(),"PICTURE UPLOADED: " + getAuthenticatedUser().getUsername() + " [" + getAuthenticatedUser().getUserRole() + "] ", new Date());
                    auditLogRepository.save(log);
                    System.out.println(file.getFileName());
                    picture = new Picture(file.getFileName(), userRepository.findFirstByUsername(auth.getName()), new Date(), file.getFileName());
                    pictureService.savePicture(picture);
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(file.getFileName());
                InputStream input = file.getInputstream();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File( filename));
                try {
                    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
                }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I would appreciated if someone could help me finding the problem.

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]: I have tried to make a clean Spring project and tried all of the possibilities to make a `<p:fileUpload>`, but none of them work. But I looked on the traffic of my browser, and I found out something interesting:
[image: Traffic after I uploaded the File with advanced]. The POST statement appears immediately after I pressed the uploadbutton, the other GETs appear 1-2 seconds after.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for your answer. I have tried to create a new Spring project a few days ago and I followed your instructions on the site you have posted, but the problem was not solved. I will try to create a new JSF project without Spring and I will let you know the result.

Comment: @BalusC What do you mean with "Spring looks suspicious with  a custom scope"?

Comment: @BalusC I have tried to start a fresh Project without Spring, but I am not able to bring this fileupload to work. Even in the new project the behavior is exactly the same as mentioned above.

Comment: Please look to this post it will help you to understand how to upload a file step by step : [Upload a file step by step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says

> **Advanced File Upload**
>
> FileUploadListener is the way to access the uploaded files in this mode, when a file is uploaded
> defined fileUploadListener is processed with a FileUploadEvent as the parameter.

Add the fileUploadListener with a FileUploadEvent parameter. Make the button AJAXical. Lose the enctype. Don't bother with fileUpload's value.